# how can I achieve an event without a click or sender or anything?

Tags: c#, .net, c++

Say for example if I want to see if ms word is started but I don't want to make a timer ticking every millisecond or if the user doesn't click a button to notify like crazy. Is there some system way to do this? Like ms word starts and it sends some signal to my application? What I am trying to accomplish is actually more sophisticated but the ms word example would suffice... .net or c++/qt/mfc solutions are what I am looking for. 10x!

Comment: You can have the OS notify you when a new application starts.  But getting another application to send you a message would require that application knowing about you.  If you didn't write it, its unlikely that the app will know anything about you.

Answer (score 1):

This article describes a method, using WMI, for receiving an event when processes are added, removed or modified:

http://weblogs.asp.net/whaggard/archive/2006/02/11/438006.aspx

It should be a simple step from this to check if it is MS word or not based on the executable name.

Answer (score 0):

You can use WMI to monitor process creation:
http://weblogs.asp.net/whaggard/archive/2006/02/11/438006.aspx

Answer (score 0):

This may overlap with app starting, but not exactly the same thing.

If you wanted to do something with the app once it started the .net UI Automation could also tell you when windows are created and other such events.

Alternativly, MSAA, Windows Automation, WindowHook are other APIs you might use.